# What does 9.2R mean in the context of RAM memories?

Tags: memory, specifications

I see engraved in memory slots values such as **1.5V** and **9.2R**. I understand that **1.5V** refers to voltage, but what does **9.2R** refer to?

[image: Photo of a memory slot displaying those values]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that it is a double riser slot it is most likely that the 9.2 is denoting the height at which the memory stick is held above the motherboard and the R is denoting that the connector is a "right angle" connector rather than the vertical you would see in desktop PCs (thanks to [kicken](https://superuser.com/users/515238/kicken) for clarifying and for a [datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1-1773929-8_Memory_Socket_QRG&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN)). This is especially likely given the lower slot states "5.2R"

Giving this height *might* allow a manufacturer to fit low profile components to the motherboard in the area under the memory stick. (Such as the 5.2mm high memory stick slot)

Having those designations in the plastic allows manufacturers to quickly determine that they have the correct part, it is not really relevant to you as a user.

Comment: 5.2R would likely mean 5.2mm height in Right Angle orientation based on this [TE Datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1-1773929-8_Memory_Socket_QRG&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN)

Comment: @kicken that certainly would make sense for the "R" designation, they may well have angled or vertical variants with a "V" or other designation. At any rate this is still a manufacturing stage designation and largely irrelevant to end users. I'll add your clarification to my answer.

Comment: The `1.5v` is indeed relevant to the user if they plan to swap memory, aside from the voltage, the keying is different and it indicates DDR vs DDR2. [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM#/media/File:Laptop_SODIMM_DDR_Memory_Comparison_V2.svg)

Comment: Interestingly, these also come in two variants of "_right-angle_", depending on which side of the RAM / module will be face-up... especially important for non-RAM devices that use these connectors, such as [SOMs](https://boundarydevices.com/product/nitrogen8m-som/)

Comment: @attie the 1.5V was already mentioned and correctly assumed to be the memory voltage. Understandably this *is* something that the user probably does care about, though the motherboard itself may support lower voltage memory. The question specifically asked about the relevance of the 9.2R designation, which *is* largely irrelevant unless the user intends to fit RAM with a large heat spreader which would be uncommon in laptops.

Comment: I take your point about using a SoM though. Some systems do indeed use these DIMM slots as interfaces and it is useful to know the maximum component height you can have on either side of the SoM board, but again this is only really relevant to the SoM or main board designer, not the end user as it would be rare for two SoM boards to use a common pinout unless they are the same manufacturer.

Comment: @Mokubai - agreed, two fair points - I was probably doing my standard job of "_too much information_"... Re `1.5v`, I was just looking to clarify the last sentence of your answer, which appears to address "_those designations_" rather than the `9.2R` specifically... unless you're referring to the `5.2R` and `9.2R` as "_those_"... :-)